# How is callCC implemented in strict functional languages?

Tags: haskell, monads, continuations, callcc

Consider the following example in Haskell of a function `quux` along with the definitions of the continuation monad and `callCC`.

```
instance Monad (Cont r) where
    return x = cont ($ x)
    s >>= f  = cont $ \c -> runCont s $ \x -> runCont (f x) c

callCC :: ((a -> Cont r b) -> Cont r a) -> Cont r a
callCC f = cont $ \h -> runCont (f (\a -> cont $ \_ -> h a)) h

quux :: Cont r Int
quux = callCC $ \k -> do
    let n = 5
    k n
    return 25
```

As I understand this example. The do block can be thought of as

```
k n >>= \_ -> return 25 == 
cont $ \c -> runCont (k n) $ \x -> runCont ((\_ -> return 25) x) c
```

And we can see from the definition of `k` which is `\a -> cont $ \_ -> h a` that in the above we have `\x -> runCont ((\_ -> return 25) x) c` being passed into the argument that is ignored with underscore. Ultimately the `return 25` is effectively "ignored" because the underscore argument is never used so from lazy evaluation its never evaluated.

So as far as I can tell this implementation of `callCC` strongly fundamentally depends on lazy evaluation. How would this `callCC` be done in a strict (non-lazy) functional language?

Comment: In some languages, Scheme, it is implemented as a primop

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. This implementation of `callcc` doesn't depend upon lazy evaluation. To prove this I'll implement it in a strict functional language and show that anything after `k n` is not executed at all.

The strict functional language I'll be using is JavaScript. Since JavaScript is not statically typed you don't need to declare a `newtype`. Hence we start by defining the `return` and `>>=` functions of the `Cont` monad in JavaScript. We'll call these functions `unit` and `bind` respectively:

```
function unit(a) {
    return function (k) {
        return k(a);
    };
}

function bind(m, k) {
    return function (c) {
        return m(function (a) {
            return k(a)(c);
        });
    };
}
```

Next we define `callcc` as follows:

```
function callcc(f) {
    return function (c) {
        return f(function (a) {
            return function () {
                return c(a);
            };
        })(c);
    };
}
```

Now we can define `quux` as follows:

```
var quux = callcc(function (k) {
    var n = 5;

    return bind(k(n), function () {
        alert("Hello World!");
        return unit(25);
    });
});
```

Note that I added an `alert` inside the second argument to `bind` to test whether or not it's executed. Now if you call `quux(alert)` it will display `5` but it won't display `"Hello World!"`. This proves that the second argument to `bind` was never executed. See the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GCTjB/) for yourself.

Why does this happen? Let's start backwards from `quux(alert)`. By beta reduction it's equivalent to:

```
(function (k) {
    var n = 5;

    return bind(k(n), function () {
        alert("Hello World!");
        return unit(25);
    });
})(function (a) {
    return function () {
        alert(a);
    };
})(alert);
```

By beta reducing it again it becomes:

```
bind(function () {
    alert(5);
}, function () {
    alert("Hello World!");
    return unit(25);
})(alert);
```

Next by the beta reduction of `bind` we get:

```
(function (c) {
    return (function () {
        alert(5);
    })(function (a) {
        return (function () {
            alert("Hello World!");
            return unit(25);
        })(a)(c);
    });
})(alert);
```

Now we can see why `"Hello World!"` was never displayed. By beta reduction we're executing `function () { alert(5); }`. It's the job of this function to call its argument, but it never does. Because of this execution stops and `"Hello World!"` is never displayed. In conclusion:

**The `callcc` function doesn't depend upon lazy evaluation.**

The function created by `callcc` terminates after `k` is called not because of lazy evaluation but because calling `k` breaks the chain by not calling it's first argument and hence returns immediately.

This brings me back to your question:

> And we can see from the definition of `k` which is `\a -> cont $ \_ -> h a` that in the above we have `\x -> runCont ((\_ -> return 25) x) c` being passed into the argument that is ignored with underscore. Ultimately the `return 25` is effectively "ignored" because the underscore argument is never used so from lazy evaluation its never evaluated.

You're mistaken. As you can see `k` is `(\a -> cont $ \_ -> h a)` and the function `(\x -> runCont ((\_ -> return 25) x) c)` is passed into the the argument that's ignored by `k`. You were correct until then. However this doesn't mean that `return 25` is not evaluated because of lazy evaluation. It's simply not evaluated because the function `(\x -> runCont ((\_ -> return 25) x) c)` is never called. I hope that cleared things up.

Comment: Oh I realize now that I was thinking that passing in a function had anything to do with evaluation of the function which is of course nonsense.